# Permission issues across servers in powershell

Tags: security, powershell, file-permissions, powershell-1.0

I wish to have an automated process that basically deploys (copies) a asp.net web site in a CI situation. I have built the web site and I then want to copy the code to the web server. This powershell code is running on my build server. the build server is running under a defined service account and i have given that account full control to the folder on the web server where the web site needs to be deployed.
The powershell code works if i run it from my local machine under my accoount (i have full control). When I run the code from the build under my admin acount it fails. when it runs under the service account it fails.
The web server and build server are both windows 2003 boxes. My machine is Vista.

I am really confused here it seems like the user credential are not correctly getting passed from the build server to the web server, but are from my vista pc to the web server. I wish our admins had a clue, this seems like some very basic authencitaions issues.

commands that a failing are Copy-Item and Remove-Item, I can do get-childitems no worries as i am copying all the existing file into a zip before i re-deploy (ie i can access the folder i just can write)

Thanks in advance

RhysC

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:
[PowerShell 2.0: Accessing Windows Shares during a Remote Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233758/powershell-2-0-accessing-windows-shares-during-a-remote-session/2234082#2234082)

I know you mentioned that Get-ChildItem was not failing, but what are the read rights (share and file-system) on the WebServer?

Comment: Keiths stuff looks spot on. I was hoping it wasnt a 2 hop issue. this may go in the too hard basket as i do not have elevated privlidges and i dont think our admin will be of much help. :(
Appreciate you help tho, thanks :)
(oh there are read/exec rights for all authenticated users)