# New-PsDrive Remote copy from DFS share errors: A specified logon session does not exist

Tags: powershell, dictionary, drive

So to recap the situation:  I am at one computer trying to run powershell using `enter-pssession computername`, then from the remote session, run the logic below:

```
$DFSPath = "\\DFSpath.com"
$RDL1 = [char](1+[char](gdr ?)[-1].name)
New-PSDrive -Name $RDL1 -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $DFSPath -Persist -credential domain\UN
```

The get-variable shows the variables properly.  But when I try to create with `New-PSDrive`, it gives:

```
New-PSDrive : A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have
been terminated
```

I did look at this: [PowerShell 2.0: Accessing Windows Shares during a Remote Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233758/powershell-2-0-accessing-windows-shares-during-a-remote-session) but wasn't able to get it to work.  Also I wouldn't know how to devise it in my script above (which will be run on multiple computers).  Is there anything newer?  I am using v3 powershell.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you know about the dreaded "[Double-Hop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx)?" If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: I just found that here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/05/credssp-for-second-hop-remoting-part-i-domain-account.aspx .  So that seems to get the session up and running but it normally shows the computername at the "cmdline".  So I start copying files like I need to and it just copies from the share to my computer.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I didn't pipe into | new-pssession.  Thanks BobLobLaw!  This is the answer for my issue.  Now I need to figure out how to add it into the script:).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of things it appears that you are experiencing the dreaded "[Double-Hop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx)". If you only what to remote to a few computers it's pretty easy to setup the "fix" for the "Double-Hop". On the computers that you want to **remote to** you need to run the following commands:

```
Enable-PSRemoting

Enable-WSManCredSSP Server
```

Then on the computer you want to **remote from** you need to run the command:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP Client –DelegateComputer [<FQDN of the server>][*]
```

In place of the fully qualified domain name you can put a * instead. That will allow you to send your credentials to any computer (that could be dangerous).

Now how would you work this into a script? There is a command called `Invoke-Command`. If you look at the parameters of `Get-Help Invoke-Command -Parameter *`, you'll see that it take a **Credential** and a **Authentication**. Here's how you would run a command on multiple computers.

```
$MyCred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1,Computer2 -Credential $MyCred -Authentication Credssp -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem $args[0]} -ArgumentList '\\Server\Share' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Now if you'll be remoting onto many machines and you know how to use Group Policy. I'd recommend setting up [PSRemoting and enabling WSManCred with the Group Policy](http://blog.powershell.no/2010/03/04/enable-and-configure-windows-powershell-remoting-using-group-policy/).

Comment: Thanks so much!  By the looks of it I won't be able to use GPO.  I may just have to run the script locally.  It's too bad you cannot do Enable-WSMAn CredSSP Server -file C:\computernames.txt with a list like you can the client.

Comment: it's a pity the second link is broken.