# Mapping a DFS using NET Use remotely throwing Error 1312.A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

Tags: powershell, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am trying to map a distributed file system (DFS) from a remote machine using
net use $drive_letter $target $password /user:domain\username

If I do this by logging to the machine there is no error, however if I try this remotely I get

System error 1312 has occurred. A specified logon session doesnt exist. It may already have been terminated.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Or is there any alternate way to map the network drive remotely without encountering these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be similar to the double hop problem discribed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746089/new-psdrive-remote-copy-from-dfs-share-errors-a-specified-logon-session-does-no).

Althought you use a differnt method for connecting the drive, I think the credential issues will be the same. Setup your system to allow passing of the credentials to the remote computer.

Comment: Thanks Roderick Bant...let me give it a try and see how it goes.